# How to avoid duplicate sanitation in controller and model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method in Rails that returns params:

```
def customer_params
  params.require(:treatment_booking).require(:customer)
end
```

I want to remove whitespace from `:phone` in place and return the whole hash. I can do it like so:

```
params.require(:treatment_booking).require(:customer).merge(:phone => params[:treatment_booking][:customer][:phone].gsub(/\s+/, ""))
```

.. but I think it's a bit not elegant since I have to reference the whole path to a hash that I already calling methods on. Is there a better way?

The answer can be both Ruby and Rails.

In general, what I'm doing is updating customer while in bookings controller. Customer can be persisted, but without password so I can't let it change it's data - only add.

Here's what's in controller:

```
  def create
    customer = Customer.find_or_create_by(email: customer_params[:email])
    if not customer.persisted?
      customer.phone = customer_params[:phone] if not customer_params[:phone].empty?
      customer.name = customer_params[:name] if not customer_params[:name].empty?
      save_customer(customer)
    elsif (customer.phone != customer_params[:phone] || customer.name.downcase != customer_params[:name].downcase)
      customer.phone = customer_params[:phone] if customer.phone.empty?
      customer.name = customer_params[:name] if customer.name.empty?
      save_customer(customer)
      redirect_to :back, notice: "This email address has been used before, you can register it or use the same Name and Phone"
      return
    else
      set_session_customer(customer.id)
    end

  < .. .. >
  end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that it is not the responsibility of the controller to sanitize parameters. But it is the models responsibility to ensure that its attributes are valid.

To sanitize model attributes I would add a custom setter to the `Customer` model like this:

```
# in app/models/customer.rb
def phone=(phone)
  write_attribute(:phone, phone.gsub(/\s+/, ''))
end
```

And keep the `customer_params` in the controller unchanged.

---

To address your comment: There is a lot going on in your controller. And IMO the controller is hard to understand and refactor. Especially because I do not know what the methods `save_customer` and `set_session_customer` do and how strict do you need to be about changed attributes.

I think it makes sense to move the updating code into the `Customer` model. That makes it easier to test. And I used [Rails' Dirty Attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html).

```
# in the controller
def create
  existing_customer = Customer.find_by(present_customer_params.fetch(:email))

  if existing_customer
    if existing_customer.contact_detail_update(present_customer_params)
      save_customer(existing_customer)
      redirect_to(
        :back,  notice: 'This email address has been used before, you can register it or use the same Name and Phone'
      ) and return
    else
      set_session_customer(existing_customer.id)
    end
  else
    new_customer = Customer.create(present_customer_params)
    save_customer(new_customer)
  end

  # ...
end

private
  def present_customer_params
    # excludes blank values from the customer_params
    customer_params.select { |_, v| v.present? }
  end

# in the `Contact` model
def contact_detail_update(attrs = {})
  contact_attributes = [:phone, :name]

  # update the customers attributes and let existing customer setters to their job
  attributes = attrs.slice(*contact_attributes) 

  # check case-insensitively if there were any non-trivial changes 
  changes.slice(*contact_attributes).values.any? do |change| 
    change.first.casecmp(change.last) != 0
  end
end
```

I not sure if this answers your comment, but perhaps the idea is helpful for your future refactorings...

Comment: Good one, but I have another place in controller where I compare the value of `params` with the ones saved and I want to avoid duplicately sanitizing the value `if (customer.phone != customer_params[:phone]` .. what would you suggest in this case?

Comment: Hard to say without knowing the reason for that condition in the controller. Would you mind to update your question with the relevant pieces of code?

Answer (score 0):

Callbacks are useful tools for these kind of tasks:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :sanitize_phone

  def sanitize_phone
    self.phone = phone.gsub(/\s+/, '')
  end
end
```

You can also use a callback to reject changes to existing attributes, using methods provided by `ActiveModel::Dirty`. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Dirty.html

```
before_save :reset_changed_attributes

def reset_changed_attributes
  phone = phone_was if phone_changed? 
  name = name_was if name_changed? 
end
```